# "seedy bar" or "shady bar" to describe a bar with criminals in it

Tags: american-english

I looked this up on google but I have not found a good answer. "Seedy bar" is used to describe a dirty bar with no high standards afaik, but is it better to use "shady bar" if you want to describe that there a lots of shady people with criminal lifestyles in it?

Comment: [Dive bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dive_bar)? I think its usage may have changed quite a bit over the years, though and there's less of a shady implication than there once was. (Not American so can't say for sure.)

Comment: I heard about dive bars too, but I think it is more a local bar with no high standards but yes I am also not an american, it is difficult to find the right word..

Comment: It depends on what you want to convey.  A very high-class looking bar can be "shady" or frequented by shady characters.  A "seedy" bar can be run by folks with the highest morals and peopled by the same -- it's just run down and perhaps a bit dirty.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I want to express that the bar is frequented by shady people.

Comment: You could say _a dodgy bar_ and it has that connotation... but _dodgy_'s very, very English... and you've tagged this for American English. _Shady_ is perfectly good though too and it does what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I will give the "shady bar" a try.

Answer (score 1):

**shady**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/shady)

> 3. Of dubious character, morality, or legality; questionable:

**seedy**    [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/seedy)

> 3. Worn and shabby; unkempt: 4. Somewhat disreputable; squalid:

Thus:

It was a **shady bar**, full of the criminal types of patrons.